# C & C++: What is the difference between pointer-to and address-of array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, auto

C++11 code:

```
int a[3];
auto b = a;       // b is of type int*
auto c = &a;      // c is of type int(*)[1]
```

C code:

```
int a[3];
int *b = a;
int (*c)[3] = &a;
```

The values of `b` and `c` are the same.

What is the difference between `b` and `c`? Why are they not the same type?

*UPDATE: I changed the array size from 1 to 3.*

Comment: `auto` doesn't play nice with pointers, it's generally not trustable with this kind of types.

Comment: @user2485710 Can you elaborate on that? Any references/citations?

Comment: `auto` works just fine with pointers, no clue where you got that idea.

Comment: @BaummitAugen In no way, I am implying that there is any issue between `auto` and pointers. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You aren't implying anything, I was just disputing the first comment.

Comment: @BaummitAugen in that case, maybe you can add an `@` with the corresponding user you are addressing :P - sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator should behave differently, for one, especially if you change the declaration of `a` to a different number of integers, such as `int a[7]`:

```
int main()
{
    int a[7];

    auto b = a;
    auto c = &a;

    std::cout << sizeof(*b) << std::endl;  // outputs sizeof(int)
    std::cout << sizeof(*c) << std::endl;  // outputs sizeof(int[7])

    return 0;
}
```

For me, this prints:

```
4
28
```

That's because the two pointers are very different types.  One is a pointer to integer, and the other is a pointer to an array of 7 integers.

The second one really does have pointer-to-array type.  If you dereference it, sure, it'll [decay to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) in most cases, but it's not actually a pointer to pointer to int.  The first one is pointer-to-int because the decay happened at the assignment.

Other places it would show up is if you really did have two variables of pointer-to-array type, and tried to assign one to the other:

```
int main()
{
    int a[7];
    int b[9];

    auto aa = &a;
    auto bb = &b;

    aa = bb;

    return 0;
}
```

This earns me the error message:

```
xx.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
xx.cpp:14:8: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[9]’ to ‘int (*)[7]’ in assignment
     aa = bb;
```

This example, however, works, because dereferencing `bb` allows it to decay to pointer-to-int:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b[9];

    auto aa = &a;
    auto bb = &b;

    aa = *bb;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the decay doesn't happen on the left side of an assignment.  This doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
    int a[7];
    int b[9];

    auto aa = &a;
    auto bb = &b;

    *aa = *bb;

    return 0;
}
```

It earns you this:

```
xx2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
xx2.cpp:14:9: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘int [9]’ to ‘int [7]’
     *aa = *bb;
```

Comment: `sizeof` also discards the `const` part for your second `cout` with the `c` variable. That's why they result in identical output.

Comment: @user2485710 :  What results in identical output?  My two `cout` lines output two different numbers.  `const` doesn't come into the picture at all.  I'm not able to align your comment with anything in my post.

Comment: Great answer. Highlights a whole bunch of concepts that I have not given much thought to, previously! I probably should use array types in favor of pointer types more often!

Comment: @KerrekSB : I first learned C over 20 years ago. That part is baked in my fingers, similar to the convulsions I get when I see `void main(void)`.  And since I still need to program C, at least that part isn't actively harmful.  Also, if you use a library that wraps `main` with something else through a `#define` (I'm looking at you, SDL), better safe than sorry...

Answer (score 6):

The identity of any object in C++ is determined by the *pair* of its *type* and its *address*.

There are two distinct objects with the same address in your example: The array itself, and the first element of the array. The first has type `int[1]`, the second has type `int`. Two distinct objects can have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, as is the case for array elements, class members, and class base subobjects.

Your example would be clearer if you wrote:

```
int a[5];
int (*ptr_to_array)[5] = &a;
int * ptr_to_array_element = &a[0];
```

But you have taken advantage of the fact that the id-expression `a` for the array decays to a pointer to the array's first element, so `a` has the same value as `&a[0]` in your context.

Comment: Thanks! I added a slightly modified version of your code to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int myArray[10][10][10][10]; //A 4 Dimentional array;

    //THESE WILL ALL PRINT THE SAME VALUE
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
            myArray,
            myArray[0],
            myArray[0][0],
            myArray[0][0][0],
            &myArray[0][0][0][0]
          );

    //NOW SEE WHAT VALUES YOU GET AFTER ADDING 1 TO EACH OF THESE POINTERS
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n",
            myArray+1,
            myArray[0]+1,
            myArray[0][0]+1,
            myArray[0][0][0]+1,
            &myArray[0][0][0][0]+1
          );
}
```

You will find that all the 5 values printed in first case are all equal. Because they point to the same initial location.

But just when you increment them by 1 you see that different pointers now jump (point) to different locations. This is because `myArray[0][0][0] + 1` will jump by 10 integer values that is 40 bytes, while `myArray[0][0] + 1` will jump by 100 integer values i.e by 400 bytes. Similarly `myArray[0] + 1` jumps by 1000 integer values or 4000 bytes.

So the values depend on what **level of pointer** you are referring to.

But now, if I use pointers to refer all of them:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int myArray[10][10][10][10]; //A 4 Dimentional array;

            int * ptr1 = myArray[10][10][10];
            int ** ptr2 = myArray[10][10];
            int *** ptr3 = myArray[10];
            int **** ptr4 = myArray;

    //THESE WILL ALL PRINT THE SAME VALUE
    printf("%u, %u, %u, %u\n", ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4);

    //THESE ALSO PRINT SAME VALUES!!
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n",ptr1+1,ptr2+1,ptr3+1,ptr4+1);
}
```

So you see, different levels of pointer variables do not behave the way the array variable does.